# How can I use WSO2 ESB ForEach mediator to iterate on all the first level object into this JSON document?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am working on a WSO2 ESB project and I have the following problem.

Into my ESB flow I have a JSON like this (it is the payload of a REST API):

```
{
    "forecast_1": {
        "country": "Rwanda",
        "forecast_date": "2018-03-20",
        "province": "Kigali City",
        "district": "Kigali",
        "morning": {
            "min_temp": 14,
            "status": "Sun with right rain",
            "max_temp": 16,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        "afternoon": {
            "min_temp": 24,
            "status": "Dark cloud with rain",
            "max_temp": 28,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum"
        }
    },
    "forecast_2": {
        "country": "Rwanda",
        "forecast_date": "2018-03-25",
        "province": "Kigali",
        "district": "Kigali",
        "morning": {
            "min_temp": 21,
            "status": "Rain showers",
            "max_temp": 21,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "There will be heavy rain"
        },
        "afternoon": {
            "min_temp": 32,
            "status": "Rain showers",
            "max_temp": 32,
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "description": "There will be heavy rain with thunder"
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see it contains 2 "root" object identified by **forecast_XXX** (but can be more than 2), in the specific case I have **forecast_1** and **forecast_2**. These object are put directly into the **root** level of my JSON document and not into a JSON array.

I have to iterate on all these objects having name starting with **forecast_**.

I am trying to carry out this task using the **ForEach** mediator with a **JSONPath** expressionm something like this:

```
<foreach id="foreach_1" expression="//*[starts-with(name(), 'forecast_')" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
    <sequence>
        <log level="full"/>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```

but when I try to save I am obtain a syntax error so I think that I am missing something. Is it the corect approach to this kind of problem? (I have to avoid to use script mediator).

How can I correctly iterate on all these first level objects in my JSON document? What am I missing? Is the **expression** a JSONPath expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xpath Used for For Each is not correct, try replacing with below code and see whether you get syntax error or not.

```
<foreach id="foreach_1" expression="//*[starts-with(name(), 'forecast_')]" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
    <sequence>
        <log level="full"/>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```